# Преобразование строки в регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

#### Описание

Есть поле ввода, где пользователь вводит какой-нибудь текст. Я должен введенный им текст обработать немного и преобразовать в регулярное выражение, чтобы искать с помощью него совпадения в тексте.
Такая небольшая проблема в том, что если я просто возьму и создам regex из ввода, результат будет совершенно неправильным. К примеру:

| Текст | Ввод | Совпадения |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами по программированию, алгоритмам, языкам программирования. | я. | `яз`, `я.` |

Нам мешают служебные символы и части, как символ `.` в примере выше.
Чтобы это предотвратить нам нужно выделять их символом `\`.

#### Вопрос

Есть какой-нибудь встроенный способ безопасного преобразования, как к примеру для ссылок `window.encodeURI`?
Если нет, есть ли хороший способ для решения этой задачи, или же просто:

```js
input = input.replace(`/[\$\^\*\(\)\{\}\+\?\[\]\.\?\,\|\\\/\`\_]/g`, `\\$0`);
```

Comment: Никаких методов для "подготовки" строки нет.

Comment: @ksa а насчет второго вопроса?

Comment: Если строка написана как правильное регулярное выражение - достаточно заменить ` \ ` на ` \ \ ` (пробелы убрать). Больше, вроде, там ничего делать не нужно.

Comment: И опции указываются отдельно. `const re = new RegExp("ab+c", "i");`

Comment: внутри квадратных скобок не надо спец.символы экранировать, кроме закрывающей скобки и слеша

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Экранирование пользовательского ввода, соответствующего буквенной строке внутри регулярного выражения, может быть достигнуто простой заменой:

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

[RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)